# Exporting Map from Composer to PDF/PRINT, but all the work disapears

Tags: qgis, export, print-composer, printing, pdf

All my work in QGIS is missing when i tried to export via pdf, jpg or impress (including scales, legends, maps, layers, georeferenced photos). I'm not using any "OpenLayers Plugin".

I had already tried to export by "Maps Printer" Plugin. The legends and scale are there, but the map no.

Comment: Well: I tried with "instant Print" plug in and it works fine. Just replace the map to the bluish zone and it's done!

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to export to a PDF go to `project->new print composer`. Give this a title or leave it blank `->ok`. Then go to `Add New Map`[image: New Map]

Then drag your cursor across the blank template. Your paper size and printing setting are on the right side of the screen.

Then `composer->export to pdf`

Comment: that's what i did. But when exporting to pdf, the scales, legends, maps disapear!..and I had to re-start "composer to recover the maps and all the settings.

Comment: What version are you running? How big of a map are you trying to export?

Comment: 2.12. It's a very small map made from two photographs (after "georeferentitation")...just 14 hectares.